# Using personal_sign with WalletConnect and Gnosis Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, walletconnect

I'm developing a website that uses `personal_sign` to authenticate users. I send the "address" and "signature" to my server to verify the user owns the address. I'm currently adding WalletConnect support, and ran into an issue with Gnosis Safe. When signing with Gnosis Safe, the value of `signature` is just "0x" instead of the full signature:

```
const signature = await connector.signPersonalMessage([
  convertUtf8ToHex(message),
  address,
]);
```

Is `personal_sign` supported by Gnosis Safe? This technique works with WalletConnect when connecting with Ledger Live or the Metamask mobile app. Is there an alternative way to verify a user owns an address?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `safeProxyContract.isValidSignature(msgHash, signature)` (See [CompatibilityFallbackHandler.sol#L66](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/handler/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.sol#L66)) returns the [EIP1271](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271) magic value, then the message with the `msgHash` is signed. If it doesn't, then it isn't signed

```js
const UPDATED_EIP1271_MAGIC_VALUE = '0x1626ba7e'

let isValidSignature = await safeProxyContract.isValidSignature(msgHash, signature)

// if isValidSignature() returns the EIP-1271 magic value, the signature is valid
if (isValidSignature == UPDATED_EIP1271_MAGIC_VALUE) {
  signatureValid = true
}
```

But what I couldn't figure out was when to make the call to `isValidSignature()`. Because the **WalletConnect** modal actually resolves `0x` right after the user issues the txn, without waiting for the txn to be confirmed. So there is no way to know the txn hash, nor when/if the sign message txn was mined or not

But GnosisSafe contract emits an event during those txn. So I added a `once` event listener to the contract to listen for that event, and then check `isValidSignature()`

```js
const msgHash = ethers.utils.hashMessage(rawMessage)
const getMessageHash = await wsSafeProxyContract.getMessageHash(msgHash)
// login() only after the _signMessage() txn is mined and SignMsg(msgHash) event emitted
wsSafeProxyContract.once(wsSafeProxyContract.filters.SignMsg(getMessageHash), async () => {
  await login()
})
```

Thanks [@Richard](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/60740/richard) for helping out!

Comment: Something I'm still confused is how to handle nonces with allowing using Gnosis Safe to login. Most ethereum logins would require the user to sign a random nonce. But that is a bad UX for users, because users would have to issue an on-chain txn on each login. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

As the Safe is a contract based wallet it does not generate a normal signature. The WalletConnect Safe App uses [EIP-1271](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271) to return a signature. The returned signature can then be checked against the Safe contract.

The Safe app is returning `0x`, because this indicates to the contract that it should check in the local storage of the contract if the message was signed. That is also the reason why a Safe transaction is triggered when signing a message with the Safe currently.

Here an example how this could be done: https://github.com/snapshot-labs/snapshot.js/blob/9deb0d53f80ce82dc84fe6090ef8d3884345ba53/src/sign/eip1271.ts#L52-L56